# Conforming dataframe dtypes between read_excel() and to_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a dataframe from an excel file (specifically xlsx) that contains rows and columns about vendors, including zip_code and tax_id columns. When the numbers are read IN and then I cast the column `astype(unicode)`, tax_id 123456789 becomes 123456789.0.

I don't want to cast to int and then mod / truncate (because, in the case of zip_code and theoretically tax_id too, '07443' will get converted to 7443 which isn't good). I just want to clip the '.0' and have to_excel() treat the whole column as strings (unicodes, more specifically).

Sometimes read_excel() correctly identifies a number as a string (07443 is a good example, actually). In the case of the tax_id though, it's clearly coming in as a number of some kind (even though until I astype(unicode) it, the '.0' doesn't show up.

One thing I've tried is `df.astype(unicode).replace(".0","")`, but this doesn't seem to be getting it done. The resulting df still shows 123456789.0.

I'm not sure how to illustrate this with code because you need an Excel file, which I can't attach. I'm open to suggestions as to how to clarify my question if necessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, one thing that appear to be working (which I suppose speaks to the awesomeness of pandas):

```
df['tax_id'].replace(".0$","",regex=True)
```